# What is PaySel column for in database APInvoice table?

Tags: acumatica

The column is set to boolean, is it mapping to any field on interface?

Where I can find the definition?

Answer (score 0):

In UI this column is called "Approved for Payment" - that's what user sets when selecting bills on the Approve Bills screen in AP.

You could find this information through browsing the source code for the `APInvoice` DAC. There you have the following definition for the `PaySel` field, which shows both the meaning and the name in UI:

```
/// <summary>
/// When set to <c>true</c> indicates that the document is approved for payment.
/// </summary>
[PXDBBool]
[PXDefault(false)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Approved for Payment")]
public bool? PaySel
{
    get
    {
        return _PaySel;
    }
    set
    {
        _PaySel = value;
    }
}
```